# Swift - AppDelegate error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, appdelegate, ios8.2

I added some fonts and whenever I try to run it, it crashes and catches an exception at
`class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {`
I added the catch all exceptions breakpoint. There are no errors, no connections that have been lingering, but I do have one warning, probably not to do anything with the error. It says `Constraint referencing items turned off in current configuration. Turn off this constraint in configuration menu.`